# Is quantile the value of $x$ for which the probability that $X$ is greater than $x$ or $X$ is less than $x$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Lets say $X$ is a random variable. What does the quantile $t_{0.3}$ represents?

The value of $x$ for which the probability that $X$ is greater than $x$ is $0.3$?
Or is it the value of $x$ for which the probability that $X$ is less then $x$ is $0.3$?

So is it $P(X<x) = 0.3$ or $P(X>x) = 0.3$

What about say now $t_{0.9}$?

So is it $P(X<x) = 0.9$ or $P(X>x) = 0.9$

according to my textbook the answer to the first question is $P(X<x) = 0.3$ but the answer to the second question is $P(X>x) = 0.9$?

I am so confused which is which. and how do I know?

Exact snippet from my textbook:

[image]

Comment: I have usually seen $t_q$ defined as a value such that $P(X \le t_q) = q$. I find it unusual that a textbook flip-flops on the definition; perhaps the second case with the $0.9$ is a typo?

Comment: @angryavian really? I thought the first was the problem? check the edit I included the a snippet from my textbook.

Comment: Your book uses $t_{\alpha}$ to refer to upper quantile, so the first one should also say $P(X>t_{0.3})=0.3$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks what about the second one?